# module import product from xml file prestashop

Tags: xml, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

hello i wanna create module to import products data from xml file to datatbase the xml file i download it from ftp server and read it and imported the products, if a product exist with the same reefrence i do a update for the product he has the same reference.
please give some ideas 
 i found this code in some forums

```
require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
        $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(Configuration::get('DKSYNCHRONE_LINK'), Configuration::get('DKSYNCHRONE_KEY'), false);               

    //try{
        $product = $webService->get(array('resource' => 'products', 'id' => (int) $id_product ));

        $sql = 'select * from `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'synchrone_products` where id_product = '.$id_product;
        $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

        if(count($results) > 0)
        {
            $result = $results[0];
            $return["infos"]["product_id"] = $result["id_product_sync"];

            if($result["id_product_sync"] == "")
            {
                if(in_array("sync_add", $params))
                {
                    $infos = $this->insertNewProduct($id_product, $product, $result["id_category_sync"], null, $params);                        
                    $return["infos"] = $infos;
                }
                else
                    $return["synchron"] = false;
                $return["success"]  = true;
            }
            else
            {                
                $sql = 'select * from `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product` where id_product = '.$result["id_product_sync"];
                $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
                if(count($results) == 0)
                {
                    if(in_array("sync_add", $params))
                    {
                        $infos = $this->insertNewProduct($id_product, $product, $result["id_category_sync"],null,$params);
                        $return["infos"]    = $infos;
                    }
                    else
                        $return["synchron"] = false;
                    $return["success"]  = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(in_array("sync_edit", $params))
                    {
                        $infos = $this->insertNewProduct($id_product, $product, $result["id_category_sync"], $result["id_product_sync"],$params);
                        $return["infos"]    = $infos;
                    }
                    else
                        $return["synchron"] = false;
                    $return["success"]  = true;
                }
            }
        }
    /*}
    catch(Exception $e) {
        $return["synchron"] = false;
    }*/

    die(json_encode($return));
}

public function insertNewProduct($id_product, $product, $id_category, $product_edited = null, $params = array())
{            
    require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(Configuration::get('DKSYNCHRONE_LINK'), Configuration::get('DKSYNCHRONE_KEY'), false); 

    $object = new Product($product_edited);
    if(!$product_edited)
        $new_product = true;
    else
        $new_product = false;

    $elem_sync = array();

    //Synchronisation des informations générales ------------------------------------------------------------------------       
    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_titre",$params)))
    {   
        $object->name = array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) => (string)$product->product->name->language); 

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_titre";
    }          

    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_description",$params)))
    {
        $object->description = array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) => (string)$product->product->description->language);
        $object->description_short = array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) => (string)$product->product->description_short->language);

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_description";
    }       

    $object->reference = $product->product->reference;  
    $object->on_sale = $product->product->on_sale;
    $object->available_for_order = $product->product->available_for_order;  
    $object->condition = $product->product->condition;

    if($new_product)
        $object->active = false;        
    else
        $object->active = $product->product->active;

    $object->ecotax = $product->product->ecotax;
    $object->width = $product->product->width;
    $object->height = $product->product->height;
    $object->depth = $product->product->depth;
    $object->weight = $product->product->weight;

    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_qte",$params)))
    {
        $object->quantity = (int)$product->product->quantity;
        $object->minimal_quantity = $product->product->minimal_quantity;

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_qte";
    }

    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_manufact",$params)))
    {
        $object->id_manufacturer = $product->product->id_manufacturer;

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_manufact";
    }

    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_suplier",$params)))
    {
        $object->id_supplier = $product->product->id_supplier;

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_suplier";
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //Synchronisation SEO ------------------------------------------------------------------------      
    $object->link_rewrite = array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) => (string)$product->product->link_rewrite->language);

    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_metas_title",$params)))
    {   
        $object->meta_title = array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) => (string)$product->product->meta_title->language);

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_metas_title";
    }

    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_metas_description",$params)))
    {   
        $object->meta_description = array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) => (string)$product->product->meta_description->language);

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_metas_description";
    }

    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_metas_keys",$params)))
    {   
        $object->meta_title = array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) => (string)$product->product->meta_title->language);

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_metas_keys";
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

    $object->save();

    $product_edited = $object->id;

    //Synchronisation combinations ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_attributes",$params)))
    {
        $combines = array();
        $sql = 'select * from `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'synchrone_products_attributes`';
        $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

        foreach($results as $result)
        {
            $combines[$result["id_attribute"]] = $result["id_attribute_sync"];
        }


        $combinations = $product->product->associations->combinations->combinations;
        foreach($combinations as $id_combination)
        {
            $id_combination = $id_combination->id;                          

            $combination = $webService->get(array(
                'resource' => 'combinations', 
                'filter[id]' => (int)$id_combination, 
                "display" => "full" 
            ));

            if((int)$product->product->id_default_combination == (int)$id_combination)
                $default = true;
            else
                $default = false;

            $array_values = array();

            $product_option_values = $combination->combinations->combination->associations->product_option_values->product_option_value;            
            foreach($product_option_values as $product_option_value)
            {
                $array_values[] = $combines[(int)$product_option_value->id];
            }

            if(!$object->productAttributeExists($array_values))
            {
                $stock = $webService->get(array(
                    'resource' => 'stock_availables', 
                    'filter[id_product_attribute]' => (int)$id_combination, 
                    'filter[id_product]' => $id_product, 
                    "display" => "full" 
                ));

                $quantity = $stock->stock_availables->stock_available->quantity;

                $idProductAttribute = $object->addProductAttribute(
                    (float)$combination->combinations->combination->price, 
                    (float)$combination->combinations->combination->weight, 
                    $combination->combinations->combination->unit_price_impact, 
                    (float)$combination->combinations->combination->ecotax, 
                    (int)$quantity, 
                    "", 
                    strval($combination->combinations->combination->reference), 
                    strval($combination->combinations->combination->supplier_reference), 
                    strval($combination->combinations->combination->ean13), 
                    $default, 
                    NULL, 
                    NULL
                );

                $object->addAttributeCombinaison($idProductAttribute, $array_values);
            }
        }

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_attributes";
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                          

    //Synchronisation du prix ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_prix",$params)))
    {
        $specific_pricesResources = $webService->get(array(
            'resource' => 'specific_prices', 
            'filter[id_product]' => $id_product, 
            "display" => "full" 
        ));

        $price = (float)$product->product->price;       

        $reduction = (float) $specific_pricesResources->specific_prices->specific_price->reduction;         
        if($reduction > 0)
            $price = $price / (1-$reduction);

        $price = round($price / 1.2,6);

        $object->price = $price;        
        $object->show_price = $product->product->show_price;

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_prix";
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                          

    //Synchronisation des promotions ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_promotions",$params)))
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."specific_price` where id_product = ".$product_edited;
        //echo $sql;
        Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql);               

        foreach($specific_pricesResources->specific_prices->specific_price as $specific_price_sync)
        {                                   
            $sql = "INSERT INTO "._DB_PREFIX_."specific_price (id_specific_price, id_specific_price_rule, id_cart, id_product, id_shop, id_shop_group, id_currency, id_country, id_group, id_customer, id_product_attribute, price, from_quantity, reduction, reduction_type, `from`, `to`)
                VALUES (null,0,0,".$product_edited.",1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'".$specific_price_sync->price."','".$specific_price_sync->from_quantity."','".$specific_price_sync->reduction."','".$specific_price_sync->reduction_type."','".$specific_price_sync->from."','".$specific_price_sync->to."')";
            //echo $sql."<br>";
            //echo $id_product."  ".$sql.'<br>';
            Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql);           
        }

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_promotions";
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $object->save();

    //Synchronisation de la catégorie ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $object->category = array($id_category);
    $object->id_category_default = $id_category;
    $object->updateCategories($object->category, true);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      

    if($new_product || (!$new_product && in_array("sync_photo",$params)))
    {

        $cover = true;
        foreach($product->product->associations->images->image as $img)
        {            
            $this->copyImg($object->id, $id_image = null, $img->attributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')->href, $entity = 'products', $regenerate = true, $cover);  
            $cover = false;
        }  

        $elem_sync[] = "sync_photo";
    }  

    $sql = 'update `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'synchrone_products` set id_product_sync = '.$object->id.' where id_product = '.$id_product;
    Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql);

    $date_add = (string)$product->product->date_add;
    $date_upd = (string)$product->product->date_upd;

    $sql = "UPDATE  `gitdk_tendanceronde`.`tr_product` SET  `date_add` =  '".$date_add."', `date_upd` =  '".$date_upd."' WHERE  `tr_product`.`id_product` =".$product_edited.";";
    //echo $sql;
    Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql);

    return array(
        "product_id" => $object->id,
        "product_name" => (string)$product->product->name->language,
        "new_product" => $new_product,
        "synchronisation" => implode(",",$elem_sync),
        "active" => $object->active
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello everyone i found a solution maybe help others

there is a function to get the file from ftp server

```
 function getFile(){


        $local_file = 'file'.time().'.xml';
        $server_file = 'file.xml';

        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftpurl);

        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password');

        if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {

            echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";

        } else {
            echo "There was a problem\n";
        }

        ftp_close($conn_id);

        $this->parseFileToArray($local_file);


    }
```

and i parse the file to another function to get the file content;

```
public function parseFileToArray($file){

        $xmlstr = file_get_contents($file);

        $xmlcont = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

        $arrayProducts = array();

        foreach($xmlcont as $url) 

            { 
                $arrayProducts[] = array('reference' => $url->kode,
                                         //get the parameters u need
                                         ..............
                                         );

            }

        $this->updateProducts($arrayProducts);

    }
```

and now i transfer the data to the function do the update

```
public function updateProducts($arrayProducts){

      foreach($arrayProducts as $arrayProduct) 

            {  

            $product_id = // sql request to get the product id that match the reference

            if($product_id){

               $object = new Product($product_id);

               $object->wholesale_price = $arrayProduct['wholesale_price'];
               // the update

               $object->save();
            }
            }

}
```